# Azure DevOps: Not able to email Queries

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, agile

I have the Project administrator role in Azure Devops for the project I manage. I can do everything in my project except for emailing queries. Is there a specific role that is needed to be able to email Queries?

Things I tried:

1. Changing my roles - Didn't work as project administrator is already an elevated access
2. Sending to different emails  - No effect. No email goes to any email within my organization

Comment: maybe your organization is blocking the emails from azure devops.

Comment: I checked. It's not blocking emails from azure devops as another administrator is able to still send emails. So I think it's a issue probably i the role settings of azure devops

Comment: If you doesn't get any error message from azure devops when sending the email, then the issue could not come from azure devops role...

Comment: _I can do everything in my project except for emailing queries_ what is the actual symptom? Is the symptom that you email the query, don't get any errors, but the email is never received?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I know project admin is enough to send email. So I think the issue is that the emails are blocked by receivers. You can create a new Outlook email and add it to project member to test that.

*To view, run, or email a query, you must be granted Stakeholder access or higher.*

*You can only send the email to individual address for a project member that is recognized by the system. Adding a team group or security group to the to line isn't supported. If you add an email account that the system doesn't recognize, you receive a message that one or more recipients of your email don't have permissions to read the mailed work items.*

**Related documents:**

[General work item feature access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#general-work-item-feature-access)

[View, run, or email a work item query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/view-run-query?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#prerequisites)

[Email query items or share a query URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/view-run-query?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#email-query-items-or-share-a-query-url)